# JavaScript: Where to define properties upon Constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm accustom to work with constructor-functions this way:

```
function Computer(ram) {
  this.ram = ram;
}

// Defining a property of the prototype-
// object OUTSIDE of the constructur-
// function.
Computer.prototype.getRam = function() {
  return this.ram + ' MB';
}
```

I define and initialize values within the constructor. Methods are attached upon the prototype-object **outside** the constructor-function.

Yesterday I've seen these technique:

```
function Car(maxSpeed) {
  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  // Defining a property of the prototype-
  // object WITHIN the constructur-
  // function.
  Car.prototype.getMaxSpeed = function() {
    return this.maxSpeed + ' km/h';
  }
}
```

The method is defined **within** the constructor-function => Without creating at least one object the method doesn't exist.

What I always consider a bit weird concerning the first approach is that someone can call the method upon the constructor-function / -object. Then all properties which use the this-keyword return undefined.
With the second technique an error is thrown.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both techniques?

Which one should I prefer / avoid and for what reasons?

Comment: The second option is NOT recommended.  It has several downsides.

Comment: What are downsides? Do you have a link to another question or some article please?

Comment: The first one is the correct way of defining a function and setting prototype properties. Second is not the correct one.

With first one, even if function `Computer.prototype.getRam` is available for someone to call, it has to called either on a instance of `Computer` like `comp1.getRam()` or using prototype like `Computer.prototype.getRam.call(comp1)`.

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate of another question where the downsides are  described.  No point in duplicating that here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you give me the link to the question please?

Comment: Look right at the top of your question.  It's right there.  That's where a link to the duplicate appears when your question is marked a duplicate.

Comment: Got it. :) Thanks a lot.